# Scalar Function To Return the Result of A Select

Tags: sql-server, select, user-defined-functions, scalar

I want a function to find the maximum allowable length of a field; executed as `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

This definition fails, why?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPWLen
(
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   return select max(len((password))) as return_value from tblSec
END
GO
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for a column alias, also wrap the SELECT in brackets

```
...
return (select max(len(password)) from tblSec)
...
```

Comment: AHA!  THANKS!  I can't check this answer for another two minutes, but you got.  Thanks again!